# Read text from file and put it into a listview subitem?

Tags: c#, listview

i want to be able to read text from a file, and put it into the listviews columns.
The text within the file will be separated by '/' and each / represent when the text will join the next column. 
Some things i have tried are,

```
ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                lv.Text = fileContent[0].ToString();
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[1].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[2].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[3].ToString());
```

which didnt work as it didnt put it into the listview.I've tried searching around for other ideas, but nothing has worked.

the full code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string fileToOpen = ofd.FileName;

                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);
                string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                string[] fileItems = fileContent.Split('/');
                sr.Dispose();

                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                lv.Text = fileContent[0].ToString();
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[1].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[2].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[3].ToString());



            }
        }
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Please include a sample input file sample and your code to populate the `fileContent` variable too.

Comment: Simply instantiating a `ListViewItem` and adding things to it won't add it to the `ListView`. Are you actually adding the `ListVIewItem` to the `ListView`?

Comment: Byte i added it! Also, i dont understand your question simon.

Comment: You aren't adding the item to the list view. You're just creating the item.. you have to add it to the listview..

Comment: and how do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add your new `ListViewItem` to a `ListView`.. you're not doing that at the moment. What you are doing is creating a stand-alone `ListViewItem`.. and its just sitting there in memory.

So, after these lines:

```
ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
lv.Text = fileContent[0].ToString();
lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[1].ToString());
lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[2].ToString());
lv.SubItems.Add(fileContent[3].ToString());
```

Do this:

```
yourListView.Items.Add(lv); // add the listviewitem to the listview
```

**EDIT**:

The reason it's splitting incorrectly is because you're using `fileContent` to add items. `fileContent` is the entire content of the file.. that's not what you want. WHen you use the indexer method on a string `[]` you're accessing individual characters.

Change your code to this:

```
ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
lv.Text = fileItems[0].ToString(); // Use fileItems.. its the result of the split.
lv.SubItems.Add(fileItems[1].ToString()); // Use fileItems.. its the result of the split.
lv.SubItems.Add(fileItems[2].ToString()); // Use fileItems.. its the result of the split.
lv.SubItems.Add(fileItems[3].ToString()); // Use fileItems.. its the result of the split.
```

Comment: Hm, that worked! However, one of my words i want to add is 'plain'. It has seperated it into P,L,A,I,N and split it across columns rather than the multiple words i have! Any reason why?;o

Comment: No.. without a sample of the file you're having trouble with there is no way for me to tell.

Comment: plain/smooth/rough/calm are the words, and its split plain up to P L A I N

Comment: WOO! You're the best! Thank you Simon!